# How to dissapear rectangle like point in Packman

Tags: java, swing, oop, collision-detection, swingutilities

My game is similar to Packman. My problem is, that if Packman will eat the point, no one disappear respectively every point except the first one will change colour like background. I know a I have it in method, but It did what I want when I draw just one point. I just want to clear the point which Packman ate. I created the window in WindowBuilder (I just wanted to try it), I hope it won't be a problem.

```
public class Hra extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    PackMan packman ;
    Points point ;
    boolean check;
    ArrayList<Body> points = new ArrayList<Body>();

   static int x =900;
   static int y=600;    
   Color packCol = Color.BLACK;
   Color pointCol = Color.WHITE;

        /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
                    Game frame = new Game();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
            
    }
public void inicialization() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Point point = new Point(x, y, 20, pointCol);
        x +=100;
        points.add(point);
    }


}



 public GAME() {
             inicialization();
       
        packman = new PackMan(0, 900, 900,packCol);

        point = new point(900,800,20,pointCol);

        check = false;
        
           
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        contentPane = new JPanel();

        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        setContentPane(contentPane);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Score:" + packman.getScore());
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(309, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        


 gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(229, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
        
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() { 
    

    @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
                case 37: //left
                    packman.setCoordinatesX(packman.getCoordinatesX()-10);
                    repaint();
                    chechCollision();
                    break;
                case 38: //up
                    packman.setCoordinatesY(packman.getCoordinatesY()-10);
                    repaint();
                    chechCollision();
                    break;
                case 39://right
                    packman.setCoordinatesX(packman.getCoordinatesX()+10);
                    repaint();
                    chechCollision();
                    break;
                case 40://down
                    packman.setCoordinatesY(packman.getCoordinatesY()+10);
                    chechCollision();
                    repaint();
                    break;
                }
                
            
            }
            
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
        });
    }
    

@Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paint(g);
        g.fillRect(packman.getCoordinatesX(), packman.getCoordinatesY(), 50, 50);
    g.setColor(point.getColor());
    
    g.fillRect(point.getPointX(), body.getPointY(), 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);


 for(int i =0;i<points.size();i++){
    if (kontrola) {
        g.clearRect(points.get(i).getPointX(), points.get(i).getPointY(), 50, 50);
        


  } 


}


            for (int i = 0; i < bodiky.size(); i++) {
        g.fillRect(points.get(i).getPointX(), points.get(i).getPointY(), 50, 50);
        g.setColor(points.get(i).getColor());
        
    }
        }   
            
        

    



            
        }

        public void checkCollision() {
            if (packman.getCoordinatesX() == point.getPointX() &&  packman.getCoordinatesY() == point.getPointY()) {
            packman.setScore(packman.getScore() + point.getValueOfPoint());
        lblNewLabel.setText("Score:" + packman.getScore() );
            check = true;
            point.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            point.setValueOfPoint(0);
            repaint();
        }
                
            }
        }
    }

    public class Point{
    private Color color;
    private int pointX;
    private int pointY;
    private double valueofPoint;
    public int getCoordinatesPointX() {
        return pointX;
    }
    public Point(int pointX, int pointY, double valueofPoint,Color color) {
        super();
        this.pointX = pointX;
        this.pointY = pointY;
        this.valueofPoint= valueofPoint;
        this.color = color;
    }
    public void sePointX(int pointX) {
        this.pointX = pointX;
    }
    public int getPointY() {
        return pointY;
    }
    public void setPointY(int pointY) {
        this.pointY = pointY;
    }
    public double getValueofPoint() {
        return valueofPoint;
    }
    public void setValueofPoint(double valueofPoint) {
        this.valueofPoint = valueofPoint;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color){
        this.color = color;
}
public Color getColor(){
return color;
}        
}

    public class PackMan {
    
    private double score;
    private int coordinatesX;
    private int coordinatesY;
    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public int getCoordinatesX() {
        return coordinatesX;
    }
    public void setCoordinatesX(int coordinatesX) {
        this.coordinatesX = coordinatesX;
    }
    public int getCoordinatesY() {
        return coordinatesY;
    }
    public void setCoordinatesY(int coordinatesY) {
        this.coordinatesY = coordinatesY;
    }
    public PackMan(double score, int coordinatesX, int coordinatesY) {
        super();
        this.score = score;
        this.coordinatesX = coordinatesX;
        this.coordinatesY = coordinatesY;
        
    }
    
    
    }
```

[Packman(for now just black Rectangle) is trying to eat the the first point(this point is firs in List too),but ,,dissapear"(Point has just changed the colour like background) the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zABhY.png)

[2 picture] result and problem which I described in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zABhY.png)

[Pakcman has moved to another point with same  result offcourse
I just want to eat the point just like in Packman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8orc0.png)

Comment: Create a java.util.List of Point instances.  As your PacMan eats a point, remove the point from the List.  Your drawing JPanel draws the List of Point instances.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc it works,thaks for you advice.Have a nice  day

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc what if the packman was a picture? would it be the same?

Comment: You could create the PacMan image yourself.  It's a yellow circle with an arc removed where the arc angle value changes at a constant rate.  Yes, if the PacMan is an image, you would create a bounding rectangle around the image so you can do an intersects or contains test.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Hi,can I have another question?I did everything you told me.Everything worked good,but I added animation changing direction and Pacman is eating points just when  if I don't move with him.My code is under my firts answer. :)

Comment: My edited code is the first one,sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkCollision() {
            if (packman.getCoordinatesX() == point.getPointX() &&  packman.getCoordinatesY() == point.getPointY()) {
            packman.setScore(packman.getScore() + point.getValueOfPoint());
        lblNewLabel.setText("Score:" + packman.getScore() );
            check = true;
            point.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            point.setValueOfPoint(0);
            repaint();
            points.remove(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[pacman after what changed  direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRgmY.png)

```
    public class Hra extends JFrame {
        Timer timer;
        private JPanel contentPane;
        PackMan packman ;
        Points point ;
        boolean check;
        ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
      
       static int x =900;
       static int y=600;    
       Color packCol = Color.BLACK;
       Color pointCol = Color.WHITE;
       static Direction vysledek = new Direction(null);
       static int newX = 900;
       static int newY =200;
       static int xVel = 1;
       static int yVel = 1;
       static int count = 1;
       static JLabel gifLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(//path of Image));
      
            /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
                        Game frame = new Game();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(gifLabel);                                                                  
   gifLabel.setLocation(packman.getCoordinatesX(),packman.getCoordinatesY()-38);
                    
        }
    public void inicialization() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Point point = new Point(x, y, 20, pointCol);
            y -=100;
            points.add(point);
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {       
        Point p = new Point(newX, newY, 20, pointCol);
        newX-=100;
        points.add(p);
    }
    
    }
    
    
    
     public GAME() {
                 inicialization();
           
            packman = new PackMan(0, 900, 900,packCol);
    
            point = new point(900,800,20,pointCol);
    
            check = false;
            
            timer = new Timer(10,this);
            timer.start();
               
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    
            contentPane = new JPanel();
    
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    
            setContentPane(contentPane);
    
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Score:" + packman.getScore());
            GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
            gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
                gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(309, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            
    
    
     gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
                gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(229, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
            
            this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() { 
        
    
        @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case 37: //left
                        count = 1;
                        repaint();
                        chechCollision();
                        break;
                    case 38: //up
                        count =2;
                        repaint();
                        chechCollision();
                        break;
                    case 39://right
                        count = 3;
                        repaint();
                        chechCollision();
                        break;
                    case 40://down
                        count = 4;
                        chechCollision();
                        repaint();
                        break;
                    }
                    
                
                }
                
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
            });
        }
        
    
    @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.paint(g);
            g.fillRect(packman.getCoordinatesX(), packman.getCoordinatesY(), 50, 50);
        g.setColor(point.getColor());
        
      
    
    
            
    
    
      
    
    
   
    
    
                for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {            
          g.drawOval(points.get(i).getPointX(), points.get(i).getPointY(), 50, 50);
          g.fillOval(points.get(i).getPointX(), points.get(i).getPointY(), 50, 50);
            
        }
            }   
                
            
    
        
    
    
    
                
            }
    
            public void checkCollision() {
                if (packman.getCoordinatesX() == point.getPointX() &&  packman.getCoordinatesY() == point.getPointY()) {
                packman.setScore(packman.getScore() + point.getValueOfPoint());
            lblNewLabel.setText("Score:" + packman.getScore() );
                points(i);
                repaint();
            }
                    
                }
            }
        
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (count == 1) {
            packman.setCoordinatesX(packman.getCoordinates() - xVel);
            gifLabel.setLocation(packman.getCoordinatesX(), packman.getCoordinatesY()-38);
            repaint();
         chechCollision();
        
        }
        
        if (count ==2) {
            packman.setCoordinatesY(packman.getCoordinatesY() - yVel);
            gifLabel.setLocation(packman.getCoordinatesX(), packman.getCoordinatesY()-38);
            repaint();
             chechCollision();
        }
        if (count ==3) {
            packman.setCoordinatesX(packman.getSouradniceX() + xRychlost);
            gifLabel.setLocation(packman.getSouradniceX(), packman.getSouradniceY()-38);
            repaint();
             chechCollision();
        }
        if (count ==4) {
            packman.setCoordinatesY(packman.getCoordinatesY() + yVel);
            gifLabel.setLocation(packman.getSouradniceX(), packman.getCoordinatesY()-38);
            repaint();
             chechCollision();
        }
        
    }
      
   public class Direction {
private Directions directions;
private int index;


public Smery getDirection() {
    return directions;
}
public void setSmery(Directions directions) {
    this.directions = directions;
}
public directions(Directions directions) {
    super();
    this.directions = directions;

        
}

public enum Smery {
doprava,doleva,nahoru,dolu;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't provided enough context for me to answer your question.  This code could be simplified, but without a [mre] that I can copy into my Eclipse and test, I can't tell you how to simplify the code.

Comment: I added all new code,PackMan and Point class is same

Comment: Your code does not compile.  The Packman, Points, and Body classes are missing.  The point of posting [mre] code is that it's runnable.

Comment: The PackMan and Point classes are same like in my question.Body is in my languange Point(I'm sorry about that).I would like to post less code,but it seems to me almost everything important.Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

I could not get your code to compile.

Here's my best guess as to what your GUI looks like when it starts up.

[image: Packman GUI 1]

Here's what the GUI looks like after I've eaten a pellet.

[image: Packman GUI 2]

Here's what the GUI looks like after I've eaten more pellets.

[image: Packman GUI 3]

## Explanation

Do not use static variables.

Do not use so many global variables.  You created a model, so pass the model to the controller classes.

Why did you make the score variable a `double`?  An `int` seems like it would work.

### Model

You had the right idea.  You created a `Packman` class to hold a packman and a `Point` class to hold a pellet.  I renamed your `Point` class to `Pellet` because there's a `java.awt.Point` class that is useful for this code.

I saved the center point of the packman and the center point of each pellet.  You'll see in the drawing code how I adjust the center point to draw an oval.

I created a `GameModel` class to hold a `java.util.List` of `Pellet` instances, and a `Packman` instance.  The code to check for collisions is also included in this class.

The collision detection is simple.  If the center of the pellet and the center of the packman are close enough together, then the packman eats the pellet.

### View

I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a `JFrame`, a score `JPanel`, and a drawing `JPanel`.  I didn't extend a `JFrame`.  I used a `JFrame`.  I don't care how large the `JFrame` is, so I used the `pack` method to pack the components on the JFrame.

The score `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` to place the `JLabel` and `JTextField` in the `JPanel`.

The drawing `JPanel` extends `JPanel` so I can override the `paintComponent` method.  It's much easier to draw on a drawing `JPanel`.  You don't have to take the rest of the GUI into account.  All the drawing `Panel` does is draw the packman and the pellets.  Moving the packman and checking for collisions happen in the controller classes.

I used [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than a `KeyListener`.  Generally, key bindings are more reliable than a key listener.  It's too easy for the component to lose focus and for the keys to stop working.  Sure, the key bindings code looks scary at first glance.  I have to look up the format every time I want to use them, which is why I provided the link.  But in the long run key bindings are better.

I coded indirect key actions.  The key presses just change the `Direction` `enum` in the `Packman` class.  The `java.swing.Timer` `ActionListener` actually moves the packman.  This makes the motion much smoother.

If you want to make the packman move faster or slower, adjust the `distance` parameter in the `Packman` `move` method.

For some reason I can't determine, the left and right arrow keys don't respond.  I coded the WSAD keys as a substitute.  I know the code works because it works with the WSAD keys.  If I ever figure out why the left and right arrow keys are unresponsive, I'll update this answer.

### Controller

I have a `NavigationAction` class to listen for the key bindings and a `MotionListener` class to move the packman.

The `NavigationAction` class indirectly updates the `Direction` `enum` in the `Packman` class.

The `MotionListener` class moves the packman and checks for collisions.  Since these methods are in other classes, the actionPerformed method is short and easy to understand.

## Code

Here's the complete, formatted, runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could post the code as one large block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class PackmanGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PackmanGUI());
    }
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private final GameModel model;
    
    private JFrame frame;
    
    private JPanel scorePanel;
    
    private JTextField scoreField;
    
    private Timer timer;
    
    public PackmanGUI() {
        this.model = new GameModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Packman");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        scorePanel = createScorePanel();
        frame.add(scorePanel, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        setKeyBindings();
        
        timer = new Timer(40, new MotionListener(this, model));
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private void setKeyBindings() {
        String up = "up";
        String down = "down";
        String left = "left";
        String right = "right";
        String pressed = " pressed";
        String released = " released";
        
        InputMap inputMap = drawingPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = drawingPanel.getActionMap();
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), up + pressed); 
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), down + pressed); 
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), left + pressed);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), right + pressed);
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), up + released); 
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), down + released); 
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), left + released);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), right + released);
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), up + pressed); 
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), down + pressed); 
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), left + pressed);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), right + pressed);
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), up + released); 
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), down + released); 
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), left + released);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), right + released);
        
        Packman packman = model.getPackman();
        actionMap.put(up + pressed, new NavigationAction(Direction.UP, packman));
        actionMap.put(down + pressed, new NavigationAction(Direction.DOWN, packman));
        actionMap.put(left + pressed, new NavigationAction(Direction.LEFT, packman));
        actionMap.put(right + pressed, new NavigationAction(Direction.RIGHT, packman));
        
        actionMap.put(up + released, new NavigationAction(Direction.NONE, packman));
        actionMap.put(down + released, new NavigationAction(Direction.NONE, packman));
        actionMap.put(left + released, new NavigationAction(Direction.NONE, packman));
        actionMap.put(right + released, new NavigationAction(Direction.NONE, packman));
    }
    
    private JPanel createScorePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 36f);
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Score:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label);
        
        scoreField = new JTextField(10);
        scoreField.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        scoreField.setEditable(false);
        scoreField.setFont(font);
        scoreField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        updateScore(model.getPackman().getScore());
        panel.add(scoreField);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateScore(double score) {
        scoreField.setText(Double.toString(score));
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private final GameModel model;
        
        public DrawingPanel(GameModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Packman packman = model.getPackman();
            Point point = packman.getCenterPoint();
            
            // Draw body
            int x = point.x - 25;
            int y = point.y - 25;
            
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillArc(x, y, 50, 50, 30, 300);
            
            // Draw eye
            x = point.x;
            y = point.y - 18;
            
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 8, 8);
            
            // Draw pellets
            for (Pellet pellet : model.getPellets()) {
                g.setColor(pellet.getColor());
                point = pellet.getPoint();
                x = point.x - 10;
                y = point.y - 10;
                g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public interface KeyDirectionActionHandler {
        public void keyDirectionActionPerformed(Direction direction);
    }
    
    public class NavigationAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private Direction direction;
        
        private KeyDirectionActionHandler keyDirectionActionHandler;
        
        public NavigationAction(Direction direction, 
                KeyDirectionActionHandler keyDirectionActionHandler) {
            this.direction = direction;
            this.keyDirectionActionHandler = keyDirectionActionHandler;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            keyDirectionActionHandler.keyDirectionActionPerformed(direction);
        }
        
    }
    
    public enum Direction {
        NONE, UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT;
    }

    
    public class MotionListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private final PackmanGUI frame;
        
        private final GameModel model;

        public MotionListener(PackmanGUI frame, GameModel model) {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            model.getPackman().move();
            model.checkCollisions();
            frame.updateScore(model.getPackman().getScore());
            frame.repaint();
        }
        
    }
    
    public class GameModel {
        
        private final List<Pellet> pellets;
        
        private final Packman packman;
        
        public GameModel() {
            this.packman = new Packman(0, new Point(400, 400));
            this.pellets = new ArrayList<>();
            inicialization();
        }
        
        public void inicialization() {
            int x = 600;
            int y = 600;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                Pellet pellet = new Pellet(new Point(x, y), 20, Color.WHITE);
                y -= 100;
                pellets.add(pellet);
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                Pellet pellet = new Pellet(new Point(x, y), 20, Color.WHITE);
                x -= 100;
                pellets.add(pellet);
            }
        }
        
        public void checkCollisions() {
            Point packmanPoint = packman.getCenterPoint();
            for (int index = 0; index < pellets.size(); index++) {
                Pellet pellet = pellets.get(index);
                Point pelletPoint = pellet.getPoint();
                
                // Collision detection
                int deltaX = packmanPoint.x - pelletPoint.x;
                int deltaY = packmanPoint.y - pelletPoint.y;
                double distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
                if (distance < 20) {
                    pellets.remove(pellet);
                    packman.incrementScore(pellet.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
            

        public List<Pellet> getPellets() {
            return pellets;
        }

        public Packman getPackman() {
            return packman;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Packman implements KeyDirectionActionHandler {
        
        private double score;
        
        private Direction direction;
        
        private Point centerPoint;

        public Packman(double score, Point centerPoint) {
            this.score = score;
            this.centerPoint = centerPoint;
            this.direction = Direction.NONE;
        }

        public double getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void incrementScore(double score) {
            this.score += score;
        }

        public Point getCenterPoint() {
            return centerPoint;
        }

        public void setCenterPoint(Point centerPoint) {
            this.centerPoint = centerPoint;
        }
        
        public void move() {
            int distance = 6;
            int deltaX = 0;
            int deltaY = 0;
            
            switch (direction) {
            case NONE:
                deltaX = 0;
                deltaY = 0;
                break;
            case UP:
                deltaX = 0;
                deltaY = -distance;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                deltaX = 0;
                deltaY = distance;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                deltaX = -distance;
                deltaY = 0;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                deltaX = distance;
                deltaY = 0;
            }
            
            int x = centerPoint.x + deltaX;
            int y = centerPoint.y + deltaY;
            this.centerPoint = new Point(x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyDirectionActionPerformed(Direction direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Pellet {
        
        private double value;
        
        private Color color;
        
        private Point point;

        public Pellet(Point point, double value, Color color) {
            this.point = point;
            this.value = value;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public double getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Point getPoint() {
            return point;
        }

        public void setPoint(Point point) {
            this.point = point;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Ok,thank you for your advice.What actually doing distance and why has to be less than 20?.You helped me a lot.I hope this will help other people.Thank you for your time.

Comment: @DominikVypalsky:  Because the radius of packman is 25 pixels.  So, I gave the collision detection a 5-pixel intersection so it would "appear" that packman is eating the pellet.